# Link Amazon Alexa Skill with few external services accounts

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Can I link my Amazon Alexa Skill with two external services?
I want to aggregate data from both of them but and I need to use two different access tokens.
Can I get them by using Alexa Account Linking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, Alexa Account Linking only allows you to specify one single login page and one access token.

A possible solution is to have both external services authentications in your login page. For example: first, the user sees a screen with the Google login option, then the redirect shows a page with a Facebook login option, then it finally completes. *However, this may be a bad experience for the user*.

To store both access tokens, you could:

1) have a database to associate the `userId` or `access_token` with his tokens

2) create one single token with both access tokens using [jwt](https://jwt.io/)

Another solution is to have your own service authentication system, and have a **web page** that the user can access to authenticate his external services. So, the user creates a user/password in your system, you provide a token, then he will access your page, log in with his user/password, and do the external services authentication. 
Then, in your skill backend you would get the user's token, associate to his account and access and aggregate the data.

Unfortunately, the only possibilities so far are workarounds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I came looking for an answer to this. It's a shame Amazon doesn't support it directly, but I can see why they do it. Also it was surprisingly difficult to find this post. I was about to ask this question because I couldn't find anything in the account linking docs and most search results are about multiple accounts for the Amazon Echo device, not linking multiple accounts for a single Alexa app. Anyway, thanks for confirming my suspicions.